# Fixed height iFrame without overflowing wrapping element on iPad

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari

I have some code which looks like this:

```html
<iframe src="https://adamwilliams.eu/iframe.html" style="height: 100px; width: 300px; border: none;"></iframe>
```

Note that the iframe includes a `position: fixed` element at the bottom of the page. It is important that the iframe **does not** exceed 100px in height.

This works on almost every platform, except for mobile Safari where the iframe height is just ignored and it overflows into the parent.

Most StackOverflow posts that deal with mobile Safari and iFrames suggest placing it inside a fixed height `overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` element. As you can see from the screenshot below, this does not work properly because the fixed element is "no longer" fixed and is only visible when scrolling down to the very bottom:

[image: Safari]

I've tried resizing the iframe with JS to no avail. Is there anything else I can do to get this to work?